# VB6 data report: Grouping using the Group By statement, without the data environment

Tags: vb6, report, reporting

I can accomplish the grouping in Data Report using the Data Environment smoothly. But I want to create the grouping via code using the `GROUP BY` statement.

I have this code but an error occurs saying **Report sections do not match data source**.

```
SELECT 
G.Code, G.Description, COUNT(E.EmpNo), COUNT(E.EmpName) FROM tblEmployee E
INNER JOIN tblEmployeeGroups EG
ON E.EmpNo=EG.EmpID
INNER JOIN tblGroup G
ON EG.GroupID=G.Code
GROUP BY G.Code, G.Description
ORDER BY G.Code ASC
```

Is it only possible to accomplish this via Data Environment?

Comment: You can set that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your query to use the [Data Shaping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Provider.  This has a SQL-like SHAPE command for creating hierarchical rowsets

That is what the Data Environment [does under the covers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240835%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).